# SQL Server: Replace with wildcards?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pattern-matching, replace

Does Microsoft SQL Server natively support some sort of `replace` function using wild cards? I gather that Regular Expressions are not available natively.

I note that there is a `PATINDEX` function which can be used to bolt together a solution — is there one something which does it more simply?

For example `REPLACE(data,'[xy]','q')` to replace `x` or `y` with `q`.

Answer (score 3):

The `REPLACE` built-in function does not support patterns or wildcards; only `LIKE` and `PATINDEX` do.

Assuming that you really just want the simple single-character replacement as shown in the question, then you can call `REPLACE` twice, one nested in the other, as follows:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(
               REPLACE('A B x 3 y Z x 943 yy!',
                       'x',
                       'q'),
               'y',
               'q');
```

Returns:

```
A B q 3 q Z q 943 qq!
```

If you do need more complex pattern matching / replacement, then you will need to do that via Regular Expressions, which can only be done via SQLCLR. Several SQLCLR RegEx functions are available in the Free version of the [SQL#](https://SQLsharp.com/?ref=db_162920) SQLCLR library (which I wrote), one of them being `RegEx_Replace[4k]()` (the `4k` version is for when you are certain that you will never need more than 4000 characters, hence you can get better performance from not using `NVARCHAR(MAX)` as an input parameter or return value).

The equivalent of the two nested `REPLACE` calls would be done as follows (and using the pattern syntax shown in the question):

```sql
SELECT SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(N'A B x 3 y Z x 943 yy!', N'[xy]', N'q', -1, 1, NULL);
```

Returns:

```
A B q 3 q Z q 943 qq!
```

But, since we are talking about the possibility of a more complex pattern, one that cannot be done easily in T-SQL, we can use a quantifier on the pattern to have it replace any number of contiguous `x` or `y` characters with a single `q`:

```sql
SELECT SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(N'A B x 3 y Z xx 943 yyxxyxy!', N'[xy]+', N'q', -1, 1, NULL);
```

Returns:

```
A B q 3 q Z q 943 q!
```

Please note that the input string was changed slightly from the previous two examples to add an extra `x` after the `Z`, and to add an extra `xxyxy` to the `yy` at the end. And, in both cases, the multi-character fragment was replaced with a single `q`.

For more info on working with strings and collations, please visit: [Collations Info](https://collations.info/)

Answer (score 0):

This post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13253259/sql-server-replace-command-with-wildcard seems fairly similar and references this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/150977/perform-regex-replace-in-an-sql-query

Another option is something like

```
 UPDATE myTable
 SET myField = LEFT(myField, PATINDEX('%Z%', myField))
 WHERE myField LIKE '%X%'
 OR  myField LIKE '%Y%'
```

Comment: Note that your sample code will not replace anything; It would drop anything to the right of the first 'Z' in each field, as long as the field also contains an 'X' or 'Y', which doesn't appear to be what the OP had in mind.

Comment: While it does not answer the posters question, this actually helped me in a situation where I had to standardize export paths (where the export path could be D:\mypath E:\mypath or 10.10.10.128\C$\mypath)  See my answer below

Comment: That's good that it helped with your problem, but surely it would have been easier to search for as an answer to a question it actually solves

Answer (score 0):

The above answer from CaM while it does not answer the posters question, did help me in a situation where I had to standardize export paths (where the export path could be D:\mypath E:\mypath or 10.10.10.128\C$\mypath etc...) maybe it will help someone else

```
-- standardize output paths
UPDATE dbo.ELDPdf
 SET OutputPath = SUBSTRING(OutputPath, PATINDEX('%$%', OutputPath)+2,1000)
 WHERE JobSummaryId = @JobSummaryId
 AND OutputPath LIKE '%$%'

UPDATE dbo.ELDPdf
 SET OutputPath = SUBSTRING(OutputPath, PATINDEX('%:%', OutputPath)+2,1000)
 WHERE JobSummaryId = @JobSummaryId
 AND OutputPath LIKE '%:\%'
```