# Replace a sequential set of numbers with special character

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, query-performance, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have a *varchar(200)* column that contains entries such as,

`ABC123124_A12312`
`ABC123_A1212`
`ABC123124_B12312`
`AC123124_AD12312`
`A12312_123`
etc..

I want to replace a sequence of numbers with a single `*` so that I can group the distinct non-numeric patterns in the table.

The result for this set would be
`ABC*_A*` 
`ABC*_B*`
`AC*_AD*`
`A*_*`

I have written the following primitive query below, it works correctly, but takes a long time to run on a huge table.

**I need help with rewriting or editing it to improve it's performance. SQL Server 2014**

```
-- 1. replace all numeric characters with '*'
-- 2. replace multiple consecutive '*' with just a single '*'
SELECT REPLACE
        (REPLACE
             (REPLACE
                  (REPLACE
                       (REPLACE
                            (REPLACE
                                 (REPLACE
                                      (REPLACE
                                           (REPLACE
                                                (REPLACE
                                                     (REPLACE
                                                          (REPLACE
                                                               (REPLACE(SampleID, '0', '*'),
                                                                '1', '*'),
                                                           '2', '*'),
                                                      '3', '*'),
                                                 '4', '*'),
                                            '5', '*'),
                                       '6', '*'),
                                  '7', '*'),
                             '8', '*'),
                        '9', '*')
                  , '*', '~*') -- replace each occurrence of '*' with '~*' (token plus asterisk)
             , '*~', '') -- replace in the result of the previous step each occurrence of '*~' (asterisk plus token) with '' (an empty string)
        , '~*', '*') -- replace in the result of the previous step each occurrence of '~*' (token plus asterisk) with '*' (asterisk)
        AS Pattern
FROM TABLE_X
```

#### Data

The column includes letters and numbers `[A-Za-z0-9]` and may also include the special characters `/` and `_`. I want to replace any sequence of numbers with `*`, but I do not know if the entry has special characters, and if so how many special characters.

I also do not know how many sequences of numbers are in the entry. All I know is that an entry must have a minimum of 1 number sequence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Two factors are important for performance:

1. Reduce the number of string operations.

   You may find it is possible to implement what you need using e.g. `CHARINDEX` and `PATINDEX` to find the start and end of groups, rather than performing very many `REPLACE` operations on the whole string each time.
2. Use the cheapest collation that provides correct results.

   Binary collations are the cheapest. SQL collations (on non-Unicode data only) are a little more expensive. Windows collations are much more expensive.

For example:

```
DECLARE @T table
(
    SampleID varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT @T
    (SampleID)
VALUES
    ('ABC123124_A12312'),
    ('ABC123_A1212'),
    ('ABC123124_B12312'),
    ('AC123124_AD12312'),
    ('A12312_123'),
    ('999ABC888DEF');
```

```
SELECT
    T.SampleID,
    Pattern =
    (
        SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN Chars.this NOT LIKE '[0123456789]' THEN Chars.this
                WHEN Chars.prev NOT LIKE '[0123456789]' THEN '*'
                ELSE ''
            END
        FROM dbo.Numbers AS N
        OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT 
                SUBSTRING(Bin.string, N.n, 1),
                SUBSTRING(Bin.string, N.n + 1, 1)
        ) AS Chars (prev, this)
        WHERE
            N.n BETWEEN 1 AND LEN(Bin.string)
        ORDER BY N.n
        FOR XML PATH ('')
    )
FROM @T AS T
OUTER APPLY (VALUES('$' + T.SampleID COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2)) AS Bin (string);
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=e40c9a9e82b92d16c10a7912cdc7954a)

That example relies on a permanent table of numbers. If needed, a table sufficient for `varchar(200)` is:

```
-- Create a numbers table 1-200 using Itzik Ben-Gan's row generator
WITH
  L0   AS (SELECT 1 AS c UNION ALL SELECT 1),
  L1   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L0 AS A CROSS JOIN L0 AS B),
  L2   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L1 AS A CROSS JOIN L1 AS B),
  L3   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L2 AS A CROSS JOIN L2 AS B),
  L4   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L3 AS A CROSS JOIN L3 AS B),
  L5   AS (SELECT 1 AS c FROM L4 AS A CROSS JOIN L4 AS B),
  Nums AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS n FROM L5)
SELECT
    -- Destination column type integer NOT NULL
    ISNULL(CONVERT(integer, N.n), 0) AS n
INTO dbo.Numbers
FROM Nums AS N
WHERE N.n >= 1
AND N.n <= 200
OPTION (MAXDOP 1);

-- Add clustered primary key
ALTER TABLE dbo.Numbers
ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers_n
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (n)
WITH (SORT_IN_TEMPDB = ON, MAXDOP = 1, FILLFACTOR = 100);
```

If that isn't faster, you might find that using a binary collation alone would speed up your existing implementation sufficiently. To implement that, change one line of your code to:

```
(REPLACE(SampleID COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2, '0', '*'),
```

Users of SQL Server 2017 or later can leverage the built-in [`TRANSLATE` function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/translate-transact-sql), which may perform better than the nested `REPLACE` calls.

You could also use a general regex CLR function, or implement something custom in SQLCLR for this particular task. See for example [SQL Server: Replace with wildcards?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/162816)

Using the [SQL# library](https://sqlsharp.com/), a complete solution would be:

```
SELECT 
    T.SampleID,
    SQL#.RegEx_Replace4k(T.SampleID, '\d+', '*', -1, 1, 'CultureInvariant')
FROM @T AS T;
```

Full regex support is overkill for this task, so if you are able to use SQLCLR, coding a specific function for your needs would probably be the best performing solution of all.

Answer (score 1):

Create Number table in any manner you like,

```
create table tblnumber(number int not null)
insert into tblnumber (number)
select ROW_NUMBER()over(order by a.number) from master..spt_values a
, master..spt_values b
CREATE unique clustered index CI_num on tblnumber(number)
```

Or you can `2000 ,3000` number only only in tblNumber only since no string is going to be that long. Keep one Number table shorter.

Use ITVF,

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Mask] (@pString VARCHAR(4000))
    --WARNING!!! DO NOT USE MAX DATA-TYPES HERE!  IT WILL KILL PERFORMANCE!
RETURNS TABLE
    WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
WITH CTE AS (
        SELECT t.number AS N
            ,SUBSTRING(@pString, t.number, 1) col
        FROM dbo.tblNumber T
        WHERE t.number <= DATALENGTH(@pString)
        )
    ,CTE1 AS (
        SELECT c.N
            ,CASE 
                WHEN patindex('%[0-9]%', c.col) = 0
                    THEN c.col
                ELSE oa.col2
                END col1
        FROM CTE c
        OUTER APPLY (
            SELECT TOP 1 '*' AS col2
            FROM CTE c1
            WHERE c.N - c1.N = 1
                AND patindex('%[0-9]%', c1.col) = 0
                AND patindex('%[0-9]%', c.col) = 1
            ORDER BY c1.N
            ) oa
        )

SELECT TOP 1 (
        SELECT '' + col1
        FROM CTE1
        WHERE N > 1
            AND col1 IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY N
        FOR XML path('')
        ) MaskedString
FROM CTE1 C;
```

Usage :

```
    DECLARE @T table
(
    SampleID varchar(200) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);

INSERT @T
    (SampleID)
VALUES
    ('ABC123124_A12312'),
    ('ABC123_A1212'),
    ('ABC123124_B12312'),
    ('AC123124_AD12312'),
    ('A12312_123'),
    ('A$B.C-D+E'),
    ('A2B.C-D+E'),
    ('999ABC888DEF');

    --Prefix one extra non numeric charector.it do not change output
    select SampleID,MaskedString from @T T
    cross apply(select MaskedString from [dbo].[fn_Mask]('F'+t.SampleID))ca

select MaskedString from [dbo].[fn_Mask]('F'+'999ABC888DEF')
```